# Git revert merge commit and clear history

Tags: git, github

first of all, I readed a lot about this, but i'm not sure how to resolve, i don't want to screw up production or master branch

this is my situation:

[image]

Bassically, now i've in master branch approx 200 commits, i need to transform them into just one commit, to keep clear the history of master branch.
Thanks in advance

PD: all this changes/operations/merges are already pushed

Comment: How about `git reset --mixed commit-hash` and then `git commit`?

Comment: You want to have a single merge with all 199 commits as part of the history? Or you want to have a single revision that encompasses all the 199 commits in a single one? If that's the case, consider using ```git merge --squash```

Comment: I'm just edited the question, this all changes are pushed already, still be valid this solutions?

Comment: git is not svn so you can "rewrite" stuff if you want to (as in modify the history of a branch, remove a branch or whatever). Once changes are "published" it can be tricky if you rewrite branches because other people might have already pulled from the branch as it was which means that it can be painful.... but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, that you want to keep only the latest/last commit in `master` branch history?

If yes, then follow it. It will create a new `master` with only one commit in `git log`. **Note** that your working tree will be the same but `master` history will be cleaned (keep only the latest commit).

First backup your `master` branch for safety

```
$ git branch master.bac       # new branch called master.bac = master
```

Copy the latest commit-hash of `master` branch

```
$ git log   # copy the latest commit (top commit)
```

Back to one commit and create a new `orphan` (new branch with no commit history) branch.

```
$ git checkout HEAD~1                  # back to one commit 
$ git checkout --orphan orphan-branch
```

Now take/cherry-pick the latest commit (you copied before) of master into `orphan-branch`.

```
$ git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Now, `orphan-branch` branch has only one commit in `git log`. Delete the local `master` branch

```
$ git log
$ git branch -D master
```

Create a new local `master` branch with the history of `orphan-branch` history

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log                  # should show only one commit
```

Force Push to remote. **Note:** think twice it will replace remote/master with your local/master

```
$ git push -f origin HEAD  # replace your remote/master with local/master
```